# Bash prompt multiple command substitution

Tags: bash

I am setting up my bash prompt in .bashrc using the following (simplified) function:

```
set_prompts() {

    PS1="\u@\h in \w "
    PS1+="\$(get_git_repo_details)"
    PS1+="\n"
    PS1+="\$(exit_status_prompt)"
}
```

Now the `exit_status_prompt` prints a different coloured prompt character, depending on whether the value of `$?` is 0 or not.

What I noticed though, is that with the code as above, the colour of the prompt character never updates. However, if I append the output of `exit_status_prompt` to `$PS1` before I append the output of `get_git_repo_details`, or don't append the output of `get_git_repo_details` at all, then it does update.

Does anyone know what is causing this? Thanks.

Edit:

```
exit_status_prompt()
{
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
        highlight 1 "❯ "
    else
        highlight 2 "❯ "
    fi
}
```

The `highlight` function then just uses `tput` to prepend the string in the second parameter with the colour specified in the first parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `exit_status_prompt` before doing anything else in `set_prompts`, or `$?` is going to be reset. Presumably, `exit_status_prompt` uses the exit status of the most recently executed command *or assignment*.

```
set_prompts() {
    esp=$(exit_status_prompt)
    PS1="\u@\h in \w "
    PS1+="$(get_git_repo_details)"
    PS1+="\n"
    PS1+="$esp"
}
```

I've unescaped the command substitutions, because I assume that you are (and should be) running `set_prompts` as the first command in `PROMPT_COMMAND`.

Comment: Thanks, chepner. However, this doesn't seem to answer my question. I know I can use `PROMPT_COMMAND` and get this to work easily. However, I don't understand why, even when I set `esp` at the start, it doesn't update unless I move `PS1+="$esp"` above `PS1+="$(get_git_repo_details)"`.

Comment: I can't answer that exactly, because I don't know what `exit_status_prompt` looks like. However, *every* command updates `$?`, and I assume that `exit_status_prompt` looks at the current value of `$?`. In your example, `PS1+="\n"` resets the value to `0` each time before `exit_status_prompt` is called.

Comment: The thing is, if I move both the `PS1+="\n"` and the `PS1+="\$(exit_status_prompt)"` lines so that they are above `PS1+="$(get_git_repo_details)"`, the colour changes correctly. I have updated the question to show the `exit_status_prompt` function.