# BASH print result of linux command in PS1 variable

Tags: bash, ps1

I am trying to change my ps1 command prompt to print out the contents of pwd and also the result of the du command.
I have tried adding this to my PS1 variable in my .bashrc file

```
PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\w\$(du -s `echo $PWD` 2>/dev/null | awk '{printf $1}')\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

after running source ~/.baashrc I was expecting an output of something like:

```
/home/some_user/ XXXX (the number returned from du) $
```

but instead I recieve

```
})\[\033[00m\]\$ : command not found
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't find an exact duplicate but this might help [Bash prompt multiple command substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808999/bash-prompt-multiple-command-substitution)

Comment: "did not work" is a really bad description of a problem. Please read [ask].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt updated question to more accurately reflect my problem/situation.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

`export PS1='[$(ls $PWD ; du -sh /home/me)]'`

However, it must be said that this will put an overhead on your system/filesystem. Just bear that in mind.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could I ask what you mean by an overhead on my system?

Comment: Everyone you press enter on your shell you’ll be doing multiple calls to your file system for the results you are after.

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

I made a custom function with the du command and then just added that into the PS1 variable like so:

```
function printDu {
    du -s echo $PWD 2>/dev/null | awk '{printf $1}'
}
PS1 = '\[\033[01;32m\]\w\`printDu`\[\033[00m\]\$
```

Comment: Have you tried this ? I think you have a mistake between the -s and echo