# How to get the output of a js file from bash?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, stdout

Suppose I have a js file (which can be executed using `node`):

```js
process.stdout.write('Test')
```

Is there any way I can use this in a bash file? For example, to set the `PS1`?

Here is what I tried:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

get_output() {
    return node path/to/file.js
}


export PS1='$ $get_output >'
```

I'm pretty sure this shows you I am a bash newbie...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BASH print result of linux command in PS1 variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60000157/bash-print-result-of-linux-command-in-ps1-variable)

Comment: @Siddhart : See the section titled _Command Substitution_ in the bash man page. BTW. it is quite uncommon to put `PS1` into the environment. Are you sure that this is what you want?

Comment: The PS1 is just an example, but I might use it sometime ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can take the output of a command using the $ parens operator.

```sh
export PS1=$(node path/to/file.js)
```

Comment: Please don't promote the obsolescent backtick syntax.

Comment: Ahh TIL. Corrected the answer to reflect this.